# Оформление футера

Tags: html, css

Хотел сделать футер с копирайтом, но что-то пошло не так... Он должен был выглядеть следующим образом:
[image: Образец]

Обратите внимание, что линия футера должна быть во весь экран, в отличие от остального сайта, у которого есть отступы. Я вставил в html эту линию как изображение(img), затем в дивах вставил авторские права. Если я вставляю линию с относительным позиционированием(relative) линия не во весь экран, а всё это по % высчитывать очень сложно, а если я делаю абсолютное позиционирование, линия  оказывается ниже авторских прав:
[image: моё]

Подскажите решение, пожалуйста

Код CSS(при relative):

```css
footer img {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 50px;
 width: 100%;
}

footer div {
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue', serif;
 color: #A2A2A2;
}

footer span {
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue', serif;
 color: #6E6E6E;
}

.div1 {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.div2 {
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: -23px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
   <img src="img_Blitz/Top-Line.png"/> <!--линия футера-->
   <div class="div1">All Content Copyright 2020 - <span>Blitz.</span> All Rights Reserved</div>
   <div class="div2">Site Developed by <span>Best PSD Freebies</span></div>
  </footer>
```

код CSS(при absolute):

```css
footer img {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 50px;
 width: 100%;
}

footer div {
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue', serif;
 color: #A2A2A2;
}

footer span {
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue', serif;
 color: #6E6E6E;
}

.div1 {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.div2 {
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: -23px;
}
```

Comment: Приведи минимальный код, воспроизводящий проблему. Так непонятно в чем проблема. Нужен код, чтобы понимать где косяк.

Comment: 'footer img {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 50px;
 width: 100%;
}

footer div {
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue', serif;
 color: #A2A2A2;
}

footer span {
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue', serif;
 color: #6E6E6E;
}

.div1 {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.div2 {
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: -23px;
}'

Comment: Ок. Еще проблемный хтмл кусочек не помешает. И постарайся сниппетом оформить так, чтобы средствами СО можно было тут же воспроизвести. Чтобы можно было тут поковырять.

Comment: я изменил вопрос, там все коды

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так будет правильно:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

footer .wrp {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer .div1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: left;
}

footer .div2 {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: right;
}

footer:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -moz-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-background-size: 3px 3px;
  -moz-background-size: 3px 3px;
  background-size: 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">Ваш контент</div>
<footer>
  <div class="wrp">
    <div class="div1">All Content Copyright 2020 - <span>Blitz.</span> All Rights Reserved</div>
    <div class="div2">Site Developed by <span>Best PSD Freebies</span></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.line-copyright {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line-copyright">
    //Линия на весь экран
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: твой бэкграунд нормально работает, но у меня линия футера больше, чем ширина экрана и твоего футера, видимо, проблема с картинкой

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer img {
 position: absolute;
 left: -230px;
 width: 117%;
}
```

это единственный вариант, наверное